# Loop inside loop within template vue

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have JSON like this:

[image: json]

I'm iterating over records and inside loop I'm trying to iterate over articles.records. I'm doin it like this:

```
<div class="authors__container">
    <b-row class="record"
           v-for="n in authors"
           :key="n.id">
        <b-col sm="3"
               :class=" { 'order-2': n.id % 2 !== 0 } ">
            <img :src="n.image_link" class="author__image" alt="">
        </b-col>
        <b-col sm="9" class="order-1">
            <div class="h2-heading authors__name text-center">
                <h3>
                    {{ n.name }}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b-tabs>
                    <b-tab title="O mnie">
                        <p>
                            {{ n.description }}
                        </p>
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab title="Moje artykuły">
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for="i in n.articles" :key="i.id">
                                {{ i.title }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </b-tab>
                </b-tabs>
            </div>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
</div>
```

Where authors is just variable assigned to this JSON from screenshot above.

It is correctly looping over first records but then inside `<ul>` this second loop doesn't seems to work, it only show me one dot without any title. When I instead of `{{ i.title }}` write only `{{ i }}` it is showing me this:

> [ { "id": "10", "title": "Narodowa frakcja teatrologów amatorów" }, { "id": "18", "title": "Co z symboliką?" }, { "id": "23", "title": "O negacji państwa" }, { "id": "28", "title": "O bibliotece" }, { "id": "49", "title": "Gay pride" } ]

I'm also able to access title like this `{{ i[0].title }}` but then it show only first one of course. How to make it done? I want to print every title from articles.records in separate list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your json this is possibly because `articles` isn't the array `articles.records` is the array where your data is stored that you will be able to loop over.

This is why when you use the index of `[0]` it works.

use `i in n.articles.records` instead

for additional details check out the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)